# Не полноценно работает GZip сжатия на сервере

Tags: apache, pagespeed-insights, gzip

Для оптимизации сайта включен gzip сжатие страниц на сервере, но google pagespeed-insights ругается на него и просит включить. В броузере под вкладкой "Network" данные приходят сжатыми. Почему браузер рекомендует включить gzip сжатие при включенной настройке? Сервер используется apache

Answer (score 1):

Для сжатия на стороне сервера вы можете использовать файл .HTACCESS. Я использую следующий синтаксис:

```html
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|js|css|json|jsonld|manifest+json|xml|amp-custom|amp-boilerplate|custom-element|v0.js)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
   ExpiresActive On
   ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 2 days"
   ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
   ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
   ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
   ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
   ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
   ExpiresByType audio/mpeg "access plus 2 days"
   ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 1 month"
   ExpiresByType application/ld+json "access plus 1 month"
   ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
```

Для подробностей вы можете проверить **[mod_deflate - Apache HTTP Server Version 2.4](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_deflate.html)** и **[htaccess Files - The Apache Software Foundation!](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html)**